# Is class an object in JAVA?

Tags: java, object

Class is defined as a collection of Objects in every OOPS Language, but I'm confused is a class an object by itself ?

If yes, Is class an Object in every OOPS language ?

Edit :  By class I mean the structure defined as class NameOfClass{ ... }

Comment: yes, it is an object of type java.lang.Class.

Comment: "Class is defined as a collection of Objects in every OOPS Language" that is the first time I hear it. Can you link *any* source of such claim?

Comment: Also by class do you mean `java.lang.Class` or structure defined as `class NameOfClass{ ... }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms, think of a Class as a layout of a building and the Object as the building itself. With one layout you can build multiple buildings but each different from one and another. If you've a data member in your Class where you point to a different Class, they don't exist until you create a instance of your class.

So no Class it not an object by itself. But every Java object has an instance of the `java.lang.Class` describing it. Such instances are objects though.